# Filter array by skipping every nth element from the end

Tags: php, arrays, loops, filtering, increment

Is there an efficient way to get an array by skipping every *n* elements starting from the end (so that the last element is always in the result)?

Basically, I have a large array of 300k elements that I want to turn to 100k or 150k.

Sample input:

```
$array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
```

Test: skip every other element

```
$x = 1;
```

Expected output:

```
$new_array = array(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15);
```

---

Test: skip every second element

```
$x = 2;
```

Expected output:

```
$new_array = array(0,3,6,9,12,15);
```

---

Test: skip every third element

```
$x = 3;
```

Expected output:

```
$new_array = array(3,7,11,15);
```

Comment: Question still doesn't even make sense because you guys are treating this array as if it has `15` values in it when in fact it has `16`. So 2 would be divisible, and 3 would not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for()` loop with a decrementing counter to allow you to push qualifying elements into the result array starting from the end of the array.  To put the result array in the original order, just call `array_reverse()` after the loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o0W0e))

```
function skipFromBack(array $array, int $skip): array {
    $result = [];
    for ($index = array_key_last($array); $index > -1; $index -= 1 + $skip) {
        $result[] = $array[$index];
    }
    return array_reverse($result);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can pre-calculate the starting index, use an incrementing counter, and avoid the extra `array_reverse()` call. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9eu9D))

```
function skipFromBack(array $array, int $skip): array {
    $increment = $skip + 1;
    $count = count($array);
    $start = ($count - 1) % $increment;
    $result = [];
    for ($i = $start; $i < $count; $i += $increment) {
        $result[] = $array[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function skip_x_elements($array, $x)
{
    $newArray = [];
    $skipCount = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($skipCount === $x) {
            $newArray[] = $value;
            $skipCount = 0;
        } else {
            $skipCount++;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: This unexplained answer is incorrect because it does not meet the requirements expressed in the question.  [Proof](https://3v4l.org/bPBT4) - given the sample data, all results MUST end with 15.

Answer (score -1):

Improving upon @Dieter_Reinert answer, so you can also retain the keys inside said array, here is a slightly more flexible version that better fits the original question:

```
function skipX($array, $x, $grab = false){
    $x = (!$grab) ? $x: $x - 1;
    if($x <= 0) return $array;
    $count = (count($array) % $x == 0) ? 0:$x;
    $temparr = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if($count === $x){
            $temparr[$key] = $value;
            $count = 0;
        }else $count++;
    }
    return $temparr;
}
```

Example:

```
$array = range(0, 15);
foreach ([0, 1, 2, 3] as $skip){
    print_r(skipX($array, $skip));
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

The correct output based on the original question:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 14
    [15] => 15
)

---
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [5] => 5
    [7] => 7
    [9] => 9
    [11] => 11
    [13] => 13
    [15] => 15
)

---
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [5] => 5
    [8] => 8
    [11] => 11
    [14] => 14
)

---
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [4] => 4
    [8] => 8
    [12] => 12
)

---
```

Online PHP Sandbox Demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/7db96

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it does not meet the requirements expressed in the question.  [Proof](https://3v4l.org/OuAi0)

Comment: @mickmackusa Actually, if you set up the function correctly; it does work: [proof](https://onlinephp.io/c/fdcfd)

Comment: Incorrect.  All results should end with `15` as made perfectly clear in the question requirements.  Why pass zeros when your function definition expects bools? The default behavior of your recommended snippet should be to satisfy THIS question. Please abandon the phpsandbox; it has recently been overhauled, but still has a worse mobile experience versus 3v4l.org

Comment: the second array and fourth array do end in `15` but the third doesn't because as stated in my comment, you have to change $start_with_first to true. His `$x = 2; $new_array = array(0,3,6,9,12,15);` starts at 0 unlike the other two which don't. So you need to perform a different operation. Sorry I didn't put much effort into a question that didn't provide any attempt of its own; but as it stands, the function does work. Also `1 = true` and `0 = false`....You don't know this?

Comment: Check it again: https://onlinephp.io/c/fdcfd (https://3v4l.org/0livb)

Comment: I am well aware of truthy and falsey values.  Your amended demo is not built to handle the exact specifications of this question.  The asker will not know in advance (or wish to pre-determine) when to use `true` or `false` parameters based on the variable skipping integer.

Comment: So why ask `Why pass zeros when your function definition expects bools?`? Also he and anyone else can copy the code and edited based on their needs... I'm sorry once again that my answer doesn't meet your "standards" but saying it "doesn't work" is factually incorrect. I am sure there are several better ways you can go about this process, but that doesn't mean this way doesn't work. It does as provided in thee examples.

Comment: So are you expecting the asker (and all future researchers) to magically know which skipping integers need `true` and which need `false` to actually get the right result? ...come on, I'm not being unfair here.  Your snippet is not well suited to this question.

Comment: No, I'm expecting the asker to do his own work if needed as should anyone, this is not a free coding service; Dieter Reinert & I provided a simple and dirty method to achieve his goal. If he can't take it and implement it into his own project, then he can update his question with a better explanation and with some code pointing to the specific problem in hopes of a better answer.